# Theme options are they necessary

Tags: theme-options, options, plugin-options

So I have decided to use wordpress for a site. But just as I begun I realized that I might need options. Things as simple as logo, favicon and possibly some parallax settings.

Is it necessary to have options or can I set the logo by just getting the uploads/images path and setting it to logo.jpg.

Then for say the parallax just categorizing pages and based on category use a specific section.php file to perform whats necessary?

I am new to creating themes in wordpress so if its not necessary I would prefer to not use options unless its easier than it looks. So far I got the 'Options Framework' plugin but am not sure how to use it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are developing the theme for yourself to use I don't see any reason for adding options if you don't want to/know how. If you are planning on distributing/selling your theme though, you might want to consider adding some options for your customers to change the settings and customize the theme.

I'd say that options are nice to have, but not necessary at all. If you are new to WordPress, learn how it works first. Then add options down the road if you feel that it would add some value for your site.

Comment: Cheers, yeh decided to not use options at moment. So as an example the sliders are just images in the media gallery that are tagged and the text that comes up on the slide is stored in the images info. Will most likely learn about and try an apply options later to make it easier for the non-technical staff to use.